# typescript can not get page

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an app that uses instagram api and has two route index "/" and media "/". Index is working fine but media doesn't work. It doesn't enter in get method. I made them in the same wa but one is working and the other doesn't.
I'm using typescript and node.
And I cant find the error.

My media route:

```js
    import request from "request"
    import express from "express"
    import { Router } from 'express'
    import { Post } from "../models/Post"
    const app = express()
    
    const token: any = process.env.INSTAGRAM_TOKEN
    
     const mediaRouter = Router()
    
     mediaRouter.get("/media", (req: any, res: any) => {
        
        const url = 'https://graph.instagram.com/17841403377847296/media?fields=id,media_url,timestamp&access_token='+token+''
        request({ url: url, json: true }, (error: string, response: any) => {
           if(error){
    
               res.send("unable to connect to service")
           }else{
    
                    const array = response.body.data
    
                    var Posts: Post[] = [];
    
                    array.forEach(function (obj: any) {
                        Posts.push(new Post(obj.media_url, obj.timestamp))    
                    })
                
                    res.send(Posts);
                }
        }) 
    })
    export default mediaRouter
```

my user "/" rout (that work)

```js
    import request from "request"
    import express from "express"
    import { Router } from 'express'
    const app = express()
    
    const token: any = process.env.INSTAGRAM_TOKEN
    
     const userRouter = Router()
    userRouter.get("/", (req: any, res: any) => {
        
        const url = 'https://graph.instagram.com/17841403377847296/?access_token='+ token +'&fields=account_type,media_count,username'
        request({ url: url, json: true }, (error: string, response: any) => {
           if(error){
    
               res.send("unable to connect to service")
           }else{
               
            res.send("USER " + response.body.username + " HAVE " + response.body.media_count + " POSTS")
            
           }
           
    
        })
        
    })
    export default userRouter
```

and my main app.ts

```js
    import express from "express"
    import  dotenv from "dotenv"
    
    import userRouter from "./routes/userRouter";
    import mediaRouter from "./routes/mediaRouter";
    
    
    const app = express()
    dotenv.config();
    
    //envirements variable for port
    const port: any = process.env.PORT
    
    
    app.use("/media", mediaRouter)
    app.use("/", userRouter)
    
    //Adding server to port
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("server is listen on port "+ port +"")
    })
```

Comment: its work that is problem thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `"/media"` path from `mediaRouter`. Since its declared twice, the resulting path will be `GET /media/media` instead of `GET /media`:

```js
   mediaRouter.get("/", (req: any, res: any) => {})
```